# next-auth credential provider signs me in/creates session even with incorrect detail or errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

Hello I am sick of this error. So, next-auth credential provider, signs me in even with errors/unsuccessful logins. It creates session for me.

session:

{user: {…}, expires: '2023-04-26T03:59:46.157Z'}
expires
:
"2023-04-26T03:59:46.157Z"
user
:
message
:
"Wrong Password"
status
:
"error"
:
Object
:
Object

my next-auth is as below:

```
export default async function auth(req, res) {
  const providers = [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const config = {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.USER_TOKEN}`
              //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
          }
          const users = await axios.post(`https://brp.io/api/users/signin`, {
            user_email: credentials.email,
            user_password: credentials.password
          }, config); 

          if(users.data.status !== 'error') {
            const user = users.data.message;
            return { user }
          } else {
            return null
          }
        } catch(error) {
          return error.response.data
        }
      },
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      ..................
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      ........
    })
  ]
  return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    providers,
    session: {
      strategy: "jwt",
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
     callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token.user;
      return session;
    },
    
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  })
}
```

versions:
"next": "13.2.4",
"next-auth": "^4.20.1",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your "authorize" function in the "CredentialsProvider" to throw an error when the user enters the wrong details or if there is an error.

```
async authorize(credentials) {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.USER_TOKEN}`
      },
    }
    const users = await axios.post(`https://brp.io/api/users/signin`, {
      user_email: credentials.email,
      user_password: credentials.password
    }, config); 

    if(users.data.status !== 'error') {
      const user = users.data.message;
      return { user }
    } else {
      throw new Error('Invalid credentials')
    }
  } catch(error) {
    throw new Error('Something went wrong')
  }
}
```

Comment: Fu *ing hell, thanks my guy! please if you could help with another next-auth question too: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7078